# Filters Joins or Where clauses TSQL

Tags: t-sql

Where should I put the filters on a TSQL query?

```
SELECT a.colum FROM A 
JOIN B  ON A.ID =  B.ID AND B.STATUS  = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT a.colum FROM A 
JOIN B  ON A.ID =  B.ID 
WHERE  B.STATUS  = 1
```

I'm looking for performance issues or good practices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is more efficient, a where clause or a join with million plus row tables?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/what-is-more-efficient-a-where-clause-or-a-join-with-million-plus-row-tables)

Comment: @Marian: I thought that too, but it is different. Both examples use explicit JOINs already

Comment: @gbn: I think you're somewhat right. He's asking where to put the filter, in the JOIN or in the WHERE, while the previous question is what kind of JOIN to use (straight or WHERE). Anyway, the answers in the questions you pointed out should be similar :-). @Goows: Please check the execution plan of both statements, you should have your answer there.

Comment: I would suggest you pick up one of Itziks books, like this one: [SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Fundamentals](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0735626014?ie=UTF8&tag=sq0f-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0735626014) He does a great job of explaining how to write queries and how query plans are built. HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no performance difference
- Best practice is explicit JOIN and separate filters (your 2nd example)

Note:

This changes for OUTER JOINs because you'd change it to a inner join

The quick way:

```
SELECT a.colum
FROM
   A 
   LEFT JOIN 
   B  ON A.ID =  B.ID AND B.STATUS  = 1
WHERE
   a.foo = 'bar'
```

With separate filters:

```
SELECT a.colum
FROM
   A 
   LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT * FROM B WHERE STATUS  = 1) B ON A.ID =  B.ID
WHERE
   a.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  You need to look at the execution plan for your specific queries and see which query is using the more efficient plan.  With queries as simple as your example the plans will probably look pretty similar.  The more complex the query the more difference you will see in the plan.

Comment: I put only a simple query since the only difference at the end of a report I'm building was this. Execution Plans were exactly the same. Anyway , thanks for the opinion.